# find thread with value

Tags: c++, multithreading

Here is my sample code:

```
void bar(int node, int value1, int value2)
{
  // do stuff...
}

int main() 
{
  std::thread node1 (bar, 1, 10, 12);
  std::thread node2 (bar, 2, 21, 23);

  std::cout << "main, node 1 and 2 now execute concurrently...\n";

  // synchronize threads:
  node1.join();                // pauses until first finishes
  node2.join();               // pauses until second finishes

  std::cout << "completed.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to find if thread with value is running or exists in pool? Example: Find if thread with node in function bar with value 1 is running? Or, thread with name node1 is running?

Thanks

Comment: Use `std::atomic<bool>` and set it at the end of function. Or use `std::condition_variable` if you need to wait.

Comment: This is most probably XY problem. Tell us what you are trying to achieve to get proper answer.

Comment: I want only one thread for node1, if node1 is already running then I do not want to start thread for same node again. This way, I want to restrict resources for each node.

Comment: If you need multiple threads for better performance then you may want to implement (or use existing) thread pool. Model with one task - one thread does not scale well.

Answer (score 1):

Every thread has a value, a identifier, so what can be done is that you can do `thread.id ()` to identify a thread, and store it in a array,
Code:

```
int tid [2];
thread t [2];
for(int i=0;i <2;i++)
 {
    tid [i] = t [i].id ()
  }
```

Then write a search function to match a thread with its id